# SHA1 hash of an array of structs in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, hash, sha

I need to produce an SHA1 hash of an array of custom structs in Swift. The app receives the array from an external source at periodic intervals. The objective is to be able to tell if the data changed after last update, without holding a full copy of the data.

How can I do this?

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}

let people = [
    Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Appleseed"),
    Person(firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Doe")
]

// Produce an SHA1 digest of `people` here?
```

Comment: Based on what serialization? For what use?

Comment: Updated the question with the objective.

Comment: Calculate the hash on the raw data received from your external source. If that is a well-behaved HTTP server, it may even give you meaningful `Etag` headers or answer with status `304` if nothing has changed.

Comment: The external source is the Contacts framework, from which I'm fetching the contacts based on the `Notification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange` notification. So no raw byte stream to talk about.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this could be using JSON with sorted keys:

```swift
struct Person: Encodable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}

let people = [
    Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Appleseed"),
    Person(firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Doe")
]

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .sortedKeys
let data = try! encoder.encode(people)

var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
data.withUnsafeBytes { ptr in
    CC_SHA1(ptr.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing, too.